# Closed complex numbers and equivalence realtion

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

> Question:
>   Two complex numbers are called closed IFF their absolute difference is less than one. 
>   Is closeness an equivalence relation.

I'm still fairly uncomfortable dealing with equivalence relation but here's my go at it.

Let $\mathbb{C}=\left \{ a+bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$
Let $R=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right ) \mid \left | x-y \right |<1, x,y \in \mathbb{C} \right \}$

Suppose $a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$.
Then, $\left | \left ( a+bi \right )-\left ( a+bi \right ) \right |=0<1 so a+bi \sim a+bi$

Thus, R is reflexivie.

Now, let $\left | \left ( a_{1}+b_{1}i \right )-\left ( a_{2}+b_{2}i \right ) \right | <1$
So, $a_{1}+b_{1}i , a_{2}+b_{2}i$ are both closed.

But, so is $\left | \left ( a_{2}+b_{2}i \right )-\left ( a_{1}+b_{1}i \right ) \right | <1.$
Hence, R is symmetric.

Am I right thus far? How can I demonstrate that R is transitive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Close", not "closed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no transitivity: $\;1.5\,\leftrightarrow\,1\;$ are closed , and also $\;1\,\leftrightarrow\,0.1\;$ are closed, yet $\;1.5\,\leftrightarrow\,0.1\;$ are *not* closed.